Error when setting the font to `phv` (Helvetica)
When I try to set the font family to Helvetica, pdflatex fails with the following error:
This is METAFONT, Version 2.71828182 (TeX Live 2024) (preloaded base=mf)


kpathsea: Running mktexmf phvr7t
! I can't find file `phvr7t'.
<*> ...ljfour; mag:=1; ; nonstopmode; input phvr7t

Please type another input file name
! Emergency stop.
<*> ...ljfour; mag:=1; ; nonstopmode; input phvr7t

Transcript written on mfput.log.
grep: phvr7t.log: No such file or directory
mktextfm: `mf-nowin -progname=mf \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; ; nonstopmode; input phvr7t' failed to make phvr7t.tfm.
kpathsea: Appending font creation commands to missfont.log.

! Font OT1/phv/m/n/10=phvr7t at 10.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not foun
d.
<to be read again>
                   relax
l.3 \fontfamily{phv}\selectfont

My Latex file looks like this:
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\fontfamily{phv}\selectfont
Hello World!

\end{document}

I'm on macOS using the BasicTeX distro (lightweight version of MacTeX)
Do I have to install the fonts first before using them? Also, is there a way to just enter the name of a font (like "Arial") and then LaTeX just will search for an "Arial" font installed in my system fonts? Because it seems to me that I only have access to a selection of fonts included into Latex (I found the list here)

to use system fonts use lualatex not pdflatex and \usepackage{fontspec}\setmainfont{Arial} assuming you have Arial installed in your operating system

@DavidCarlisle thank you very much. Worked great for me, luatex is installed in BasicTeX, no setup needed. Seems to work with any font family on my PC

to use system fonts use lualatex not pdflatex and
\usepackage{fontspec}\setmainfont{Arial}

assuming you have Arial installed in your operating system

But do you have any idea why my example falls?

@axolotlKing0722 your example works without error with pdflatex (not lualatex as phv name is only set up for legacy tex encodings)  but by design basictex is missing most packages so will fail on almost anything not using default settings. Probably tlmgr install psnfss (or whatever the equivalent is in the mactex GUI) will install what is needed, but really unless you are very short on disk space, install texlive full rather than a minimal subset unless you are happy to get missing file errors and know which packages need to be  installed to get the missing parts
